# Нет подсказок при использовании commonjs вместе с TypeScript-ом

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellisense, commonjs

Почему если использую commonjs в TypeScript нет подсказок IntelliSense, а если использую es6module, то тогда они есть. Где это можно изменить?

```
import fs from "fs";
const fss = require('fs')
```

[image: ESmodule есть подсказки]

[image: Commonjs нет подсказок]

Comment: Возможно в самом `.tsconfig`?

Comment: попробуйте установить @types/node в devDepencies

Comment: уже установлено, почему то ts определяет fss как any.

Comment: А по `fss.defailt` тоже нет подсказок?

Comment: нету подсказок, ts определяет его как any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TypeScript-specific `import module = require("module")` must be used to import the module.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)

```
import fss = require('fs')
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что не в этом дело: у меня и с `const fs = require("fs")` подсказки есть.

Comment: Да, в этом было дело теперь ts все правильно подсказывает